# (XYZ) Account not is not linked to YouTube account : YoutTubeException in Android

Tags: android, exception, youtube

I am facing the following issue while uploading the video from my android application.

Exception : **(XYZ) Account is not linked to YouTube account**

This is the exception that i am getting while starting to upload.

Please let me know, Any solution for the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Exception occurs when you are trying to use account that are not already configured with youtube.

Once login in youtube using that account. try [this](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?uilel=3&service=youtube&passive=true&continue=http://www.youtube.com/signin?action_handle_signin=true&feature=header&nomobiletemp=1&hl=en_US&next=%252F&hl=en_US&ltmpl=sso) once and then try on android

Comment: But It was working fine before.I have uploaded few videos and can see that got uploaded in the youtube by logging in to that particular account.